# alter column table and make default value to empty string

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Good day, just want to ask, is it possible to alter a column table and make the default value to empty string.

I tried using this query,

```
Alter Table Employee Alter Column sJobTitle Varchar(200) DEFAULT ''
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't work..

Please let me know, if 'm doing it correct..

Thanks,

Link

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to add a constraint.

Referring to [SQL SERVER – Create Default Constraint Over Table Column](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/05/31/sql-server-create-default-constraint-over-table-column/)

```
ALTER TABLE Employee 
  ADD CONSTRAINT DF_Employee _JobTitle
  DEFAULT '' FOR sJobTitle
```

Answer (score 6):

try this query. this query does not change current datas to default.

```
ALTER TABLE Employee
ADD DEFAULT ('') FOR sJobTitle
```

maybe it work.

Answer (score 2):

```
ALTER TABLE Employee 
ADD sJobTitle varchar(200) NOT NULL DEFAULT ''
```

simplest answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, single and multiple column

Single column:

```
ALTER TABLE `DBname`.`table_name` 
 MODIFY COLUMN `foo_name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '';
```

multiple column:

```
ALTER TABLE `DBname`.`table_name`
 MODIFY COLUMN `foo_name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
 MODIFY COLUMN `foo_roll` VARCHAR(65) NOT NULL DEFAULT '';
```